# MVC4 using two models for 2 different related tables on one view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, model-view-controller

I'm very new to MVC.
I have visual studio 2010 and MVC 4.

as most articles I read, I have to create a model class, and then add Controller which generate (create, delete, details, Edit and Index views).

now suppose that I have two related tables, like: Company and CompanyBranches.

I can create model, controller and views for each one individually but I can't combine 2 views (I want to modify the details view of Company, to display all related CompanyBranches on it.).

How can I do this? Knowing that I tried to add a reference for Company Branches model to Company details view, but it looks like adding two models is not allowed on MVC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a Model or ViewModel for this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   public Company MyCompany { get; set;}
   public CompanyBranches MyCompanyBranches { get; set;}

   //If you have multiple items, you can do this:
   public IList<CompanyBranches> LstCompanyBranches { get; set;}
}
```

Then this is what you will pass to your view:

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
   ViewModel model = new ViewModel();
   model.MyCompany = //populate your Company details class
   model.MyCompanyBranches = //populate your CompanyBranchess class

   return View(model); //return your view with two classes on one class
}
```

Comment: When I write @model IEnumerable<AttendanceProject.Models.ViewModel> on the view, the following error is displayed when loading the page: The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'AttendanceProject.Models.CompanyRelatedBranches', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[AttendanceProject.Models.CompanyRelatedBranches]'.

Comment: It should be @model AttendanceProject.Models.ViewModel

Then in order to access the properties of your CompanyRelatedBranches, you would call them like this: Model.CompanyRelate‌​dBranches.Property

Comment: I have already tried that, but then VS mark the following loop as error: @foreach (var item in Model) { 

    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.companyBranches.branchName);

}

Comment: I updated my code, you are doing it wrong since you are ienumerating on list of branches. Check my updated code where I put a List on my View Model. @user6218508

Comment: Finally it's worked! Thank you very much.